# split files in corresponding folders

Tags: unix, file-io

I have a list of files, for example (pippo1.txt, pippo2.txt, pippo3.txt, ecc) in a master folder called "test".

I would like to create a number of folders equal to the number of files and with the same name. For example, if I have a file called pippo1.txt, I would like to create a folder called pippo1 and then I would like to copy the .txt files in folders called pippo1, pippo2, pippo3 respectively so that pippo1.txt will stay in folder pippo1, pippo2.txt will stay in folder pippo2 ecc.

I have 14469 files.txt to allocate in 14469 folders.

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In  Bourne shell:

```
for i in *.txt
do 
  dir=$(echo $i | sed 's/.txt$//')
  mkdir "$dir"
  cp "$i" "$dir"
done
```

In `bash` you can use `${}` construction insted of `sed`:

```
for i in *.txt
do 
  dir=${i%.txt}
  mkdir "$dir"
  cp "$i" "$dir"
done
```

If you want to move the file and not copy it, just use `mv` instead of `cp`.

When you think that your list is too big for the command line (but it seems not to be too large in you case) you can use `while...read` instead of `for`:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -name '*.txt' | while read i
do 
  dir=${i%.txt}
  mkdir "$dir"
  cp "$i" "$dir"
done
```

Comment: That'd probably do it, but if there are lots and lots of files, that might overflow the shell expansion of `*.txt`.  Something like `ls *.txt | while read i; do ...` would avoid that problem.

Comment: Actually (what was I thinking?!), `ls *.txt` would suffer from the same problem.  `find . -maxdepth 1 -name \*.txt | while read i; do ...` would do it (the `\*` escapes the asterisk so it's passed to `find` unexpanded).

Comment: I might be mistaken, but I thought that the bourne shell only supported backticks for command substitution (not the `$()` syntax).  Also, the `${variable%pattern}` syntax *is* POSIX compliant, so it's pretty safe to assume that his shell supports that.

Comment: @TimPote: First one wrong, second one right: `$()` and `${...}` are both perfectly portable.

Comment: @JoSo Yeah but does the *Bourne shell* support it (as IgorChubin claims)?  I don't have a copy of the Bourne shell to test it on, but [this man page](http://heirloom.sourceforge.net/sh/sh.1.html) doesn't seem to have `$()` as a feature.

Comment: @TimPote: Yes, Bourne shell supports `$()`. I've just checked it. And it supports `${}` too. So one may always use `${}` and don't use `sed` at all.

Answer (score 0):

```
for file in *.txt; do
  newdir="${file%.txt}"
  mkdir -p "$newdir"
  mv "$file" "$newdir"
done
```

If you want to keep a copy of `pippo1.txt` in the "master directory", use `cp` instead of `mv`.  E.g.:

```
cp "$file" "$newdir"
```